# Trouble installing WSO2 API Manager 1.7.1 features on ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I would like to install API Manager 1.7.1 feature on ESB 4.8.1 and receiving this as a message summary. Any help for steps to proceed from here.

```
Your original install request has been modified. org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group-4.2.2 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.module.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.feature.group-2.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.community.features.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.event.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.application.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.mediators.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.sequences.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.datapublisher.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.mediation.templates.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.application.mgt.synapse.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.relay.server.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.feature.group-2.1.2.wso2v4 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.localentry.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.logging.mgt.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.2 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.apache.synapse.wso2.feature.group-2.1.2.wso2v4 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.properties.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.event.common.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.task.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.throttle.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.rule.mediation.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.mediation.security.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.core.runtime.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.ui.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed.
org.wso2.carbon.core.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list.


Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Key Store Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4)
Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 4.2.2) WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 4.2.0)

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Key Store Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group 
[4.2.2]

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 
[4.2.0]

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 
[4.2.2]

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1) To: org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.feature.group  [4.2.0]

Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group [4.2.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues when trying to install any of the features on top of any other wso2 product.

A work-around would be to uncheck the "bundles"(underneath the feauture - eg API Manager - uncheck Key Store bundle) that are causing the dependancy issues.

Hope this helps. I am having a lot of these conflicts when adding: AppServ to Carbon , MessageBroker to ApplicationServ.

Comment: But did it help? I am facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to rather not try and bundle these whole products together , as there are too many issues and bugs etc etc, but rather to run them in standalone mode and utilize SSO.